# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u05a0' in position 85: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, json, unicode, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to input a json format file in my database. I have some Unicode values in my json format.
for the reference of Unicode error please see this link 
: [Getting Unicode error while using insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792483/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u05a0-in-position-3)

Which I have resolved by using codecs [Description for Codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)
and the solution provided by  above solution.

But now as I'm executing insert statement I'm getting error as the title.

My Python code look like:

```
import MySQLdb
import json



db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root",         # your username
                 passwd="password",  # your password
                 db="Mydb",)        # name of the data base


cursor = db.cursor()
json_file = open('asda.txt', 'r' )
file_data = json.load(json_file)
print(file_data)
print(type(file_data))

datas = file_data['datads']
print(datas)
for data in datas:
       print(data)
       print()
       print(data['first_col'])
       ex_statement = u"INSERT INTO `tablename` (`id`, `xv`) VALUES ( {id '"+unicode(data['first_col'])+ u"'}, {xv  '"+unicode(data['second_col'])+u"'});"
       #ex_statement = "Insert into `tablename` values {first_col '"+str(data['first_col'])+"'}, {second_col  '"+str(data['second_col'])+"'});"
       cursor.execute(ex_statement)
       cursor.commit()

db.close()
```

My Json file look as :

```
{"datads" :[{
     "first_col" : "SoomeVAlue_1",
     "second_col" : "SomeValue_1_1"
},
 {
     "first_col" : " Unicode_Start ֠  Unicode_End",
     "second_col" : "SomeValue_2_2"
},
{
     "first_col" : null ,
     "second_col" : "SomeValue_2_2"
}
]}
```

My Table looks like :
[DataBase Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfOE2.png)

And after executing file I'm getting error as :

```
{u'datads': [{u'first_col': u'SoomeVAlue_1', u'second_col': u'SomeValue_1_1'}, {u'first_col': u' Unicode_Start \u05a0  Unicode_End', u'second_col': u'SomeValue_2_2'}, {u'first_col': None, u'second_col': u'SomeValue_2_2'}]}
<type 'dict'>
[{u'first_col': u'SoomeVAlue_1', u'second_col': u'SomeValue_1_1'}, {u'first_col': u' Unicode_Start \u05a0  Unicode_End', u'second_col': u'SomeValue_2_2'}, {u'first_col': None, u'second_col': u'SomeValue_2_2'}]
{u'first_col': u'SoomeVAlue_1', u'second_col': u'SomeValue_1_1'}
()
SoomeVAlue_1
{u'first_col': u' Unicode_Start \u05a0  Unicode_End', u'second_col': u'SomeValue_2_2'}
()
 Unicode_Start ֠  Unicode_End
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 35, in <module>
    cursor.execute(ex_statement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 188, in execute
    query = query.encode(db.encoding)




UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u05a0' in position 85: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Please Help me with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that your database connection uses Latin1 (`db.encoding` is `'latin1'` inside .../MySQLdb/cursors.py). `MySQLdb` advertise that it accepts a `charset` parameter, so you should try:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root",         # your username
                 passwd="password",  # your password
                 db="Mydb",          # name of the data base
                 charset="utf-8",)   # charset for the connection
```

If it is still not enough, you could have to switch to a Python 3 version along with a more recent connector like [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) that supports Python3. As Python3 natively supports unicode, you should have no longer conversion problems.